# How to Make Short Code for 100 TAG POS (iMacros)?

Tags: imacros

```
VERSION BUILD=9030808 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=aria-label:Options
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Delete
WAIT SECOND = 3
TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=aria-label:Options
TAG POS=2 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Delete
```

To...

```
TAG POS=100 TYPE=A ATTR=aria-label:Options
TAG POS=100 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Delete
```

**Note : There are 100 rows on 1 page.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `!LOOP` and use the loop functionality of IMacros (It is under the repeat section of IMacros) and set the number of times to loop, the you need to press `Play (Loop)`. Refer the below sample code!

```
VERSION BUILD=9030808 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !LOOP 1
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=A ATTR=aria-label:Options
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Delete
WAIT SECOND = 3
```

Comment: @momomo can you please give details of the project, client I will be dealing with, other details to my Gmail account...I need more details to decide